# What is the photon interception radius of a Schwarzschild black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, orbital-motion, event-horizon, gravitational-lensing

To clarify what i mean by "photon interception radius" I mean the radius of the sphere where if any photons from a distant source enter will also inevitably result in them entering the black hole.

The photon interception radius must be at least the Schwarzschild radius since even without gravity a photon would still cross the event horizon.

[image]

It must also be greater than the photon sphere as while light can orbit there there is no way to exit or enter, any orbiting light must have been emitted sideways by matter on the way through. Any incoming light must come from further out and with a steeper angle.

[image]

My main question is at what radius a passing photon must be from a Schwarzschild black hole to avoid being pulled in and crossing the event horizon?

[image]

My secondary questions are how much orbiting/curving a borderline captured photon would undergo before crossing the horizon as well as how much orbiting/curving an infinitesimally further out  escaping borderline photon would undergo before escaping into asymptotically flat space.
(I imagine one of these would result in an arbitrarily close to infinite number of orbits meaning the point/angle at which it crosses the event horizon/escapes into infinity is undefined but I might be wrong. And while I drew the borderline photon crossing the event horizon at 180°/half an orbit worth or rotation I have no idea what it actually is, I just picked 180 because proper spiraling would be hard to draw.)

Comment: This might help - [How to Understand the Black Hole Image](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUyH3XhpLTo). And this [First Image of a Black Hole!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_GVbuddri8)

Comment: Possible duplicates: [What is the Critical impact parameter for photons of a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/558638/180269), [What is the capture cross-section of a black hole region for ultra-relativistic particles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52315/180269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is "critical impact parameter". As explained in this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/558665, the critical value of $X$ is $3\sqrt{3}$.

To answer your secodary question: Your intuition is correct, as the impact parameter approaches its critical value the scattering angle will approach infinity, i.e. the photon will make an arbitrarily large number of loops before scattering back to infinity. (Note that since real photons are not perfect point particles, but wavepackets, there is a practical limit on how many loops can be achieved.)